# Server for customer payments

Tags: server, sharing, online-payment, terminal-emulator

I have online payment terminal. For customer to use it he have to open a link in browser on a phone to continue through payment forms. Firstly a have to give him (a customer) the link with terminal by sending him a message.

I need to give a customer an easiest way possible to pay through online terminal without messing around with sending messages

I developed a method by giving them QR code with the link but due to lack of tech culture many customers don't know how to use it.

Additions:
Customers have to enter card data (card number, cvv, expiration data) manualy in forms provided by url link everytime they make payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stripe.com](https://stripe.com/) offers easily-customized online, in-person, and mobile payment processing. There are [free and open source modules](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Stripe) to access stripe's web-based HTTPS API.

[PayPal](https://paypal.com) has worked well for many years processing our low-volume transactions. And it is about the only way to make purchases on [eBay](https://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2F&campid=5338215241&toolid=20008). PayPal offers a chip reader for customers to make credit card payments with. And there are also [free and open source modules](https://metacpan.org/release/Business-PayPal-API) and a developer sandbox to test transactions on. PayPal is a few cents cheaper per-transaction than stripe. There is a PayPal Marketplace too.

This [review of PayPal and Stripe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQEWYLdMSIQ) found on YouTube agrees that stripe has more options for customization, programming via the API, and documentation for doing more with it from mobile apps to POS. It looks like it would be fun to work with.

Paypal and Stripe are about the two largest payment processors. A family member uses a thing called [Square](https://squareup.com/) in her store. She likes the chip reader for credit cards that plugs into her phone to make payments there.

Comment: Thanks, i will check them. Still open for suggestions.

Comment: Researching... Adding things when they come to mind.

Comment: That last Square chip thing is very interesting, it could posibly do the trick.

Comment: Paypal offers one of those too, and stripe too, I think.